# Ant Sql task, postgres and SSL

Tags: postgresql, ssl, ant

I'm trying to write an ANT script that connects to a remote (on Heroku) Postgres instance:

```
<sql driver="org.postgresql.Driver" url="${db.url}" userid="${db.username}" password="${db.password}" >
  <transaction  src="drop/tables_and_data.sql"/>
  ....
</sql>
```

The properties file that my ANT script uses looks like this:

```
db.url=jdbc:postgresql://<host>:<port>/<database>
db.username=<username>
db.password=<password>
```

I need to tell the driver to use SSL. SSL does not appear to be a property of the SQL target and google isn't helping me find a way to add it the URL.

Comment: Does this help: http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/ssl-client.html

Comment: What about [adding](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html#connection-parameters) the ssl key to URL e.g. `jdbc:postgresql://<host>:<port>/<db>?ssl=true`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was a syntax issue. This is what I needed:

```
jdbc:postgresql://<host>:<port>/<database>?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
```